# Custom theme as feature

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, npm

so i'm creating an app that needs a dashboard where the user can adjust a "custom" css layout, i cant think on a solution for this problem. You have something in mind that could help me accomplish a solution for this?
Thanks.

Im currently using expressjs and mongoose if you need to know.

Comment: front-end will send you via a `POST` the name of the theme when the user will try to change it and you will save it in the `users` collection for that `user id`.

The front-end app will use the default theme, unless it gets the theme name via a `GET` and apply new css. 

Also you could use local storage for this feature.

EDIT: I assume that the user can pick theme from predefined names (templates) like "Dark", "Light" theme etc.

Comment: Oh ok, thats simples. Thank you, I had not thought about this perspective.

Comment: Local storage will make it even simplier. If you don't have strong business requirements about saving it to the database you can use it. cheers! 

Edit: I posted it as an answer to be more clear and visible

Comment: if you want to can mark the answer as accepted - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`front-end` will send you via a `POST` the name of the theme when the user will try to change it and you will save it in the users collection for that user id. The `front-end` app will use the default theme, unless it gets the theme name via a `GET` and apply new css.

Also, you could use local storage for this feature.

EDIT: I assume that the user can pick theme from predefined names (templates) like "Dark", "Light" theme etc.